# Android: scale several buttons to screen size

Tags: android, button, adt, scale

i've got a problem. In my app I have some (3-4) buttons which a want to scale automaticly to the full screen size. (Not a only a single button but all together). At the moment i'm using LinearLayout for my app. Is it possible to do this with it?
Sorry for my bad english.

Greetings Nils

That screen of the game "Dont't tap the White" is similar to like I'd like it:
[image]

Comment: set width "fill_parent" for each button

Comment: i think 3 relative layout in horizontal mode with parent left and parent right can help you. just one of the methods flash my mind

Comment: 3 Horizontal oriented linearLayouts with the same weight inside Vertical LinearLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Weight concept for it. Your buttons will be look same in all screens.

Firstly divide screen in 2 horizontal parts with width weight 50 50 each and height match parent. Then Add 3 buttons to each parts with weight in height as 33.33 as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="33.33"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="33.33"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="33.33"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="33.33"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="33.33"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="33.33"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can replace your weights with cleaner values, like "1", since it's the actual sum of these values that is used for calculating the distribution of the rest

Comment: jcxavier  we can use 1 or 100 both for distribution of weights

Answer (score 1):

The ugly solution would be using 3 weighted LinearLayouts (with the same weight) vertically, while using a weighted horizontal LinearLayout to achieve the same effect horizontally.

Or you could use a GridView to achieve a similar effect in a more elegant way: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

Set width of Button to match_parent. Then it will scale to fit the parent.

Answer (score 0):

yes..YOu can do it using LinearLayout. you have to set android:layout_weight=""  to the buttons..it depends the number of buttons horizontally and vertically to give weights..

Comment: please tell me how many buttons you have horizontally and vertically.. i then will post the code of LinearLayout here..

Comment: ok..i had the same code as the above answer you have accepted..but i was waiting for our response to give the exact answer you want..any ways...I think i my answer deserves an up vote :)

Answer (score 0):

use this Xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```